# Can't reshape from wide to long for multiple variables

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape, long-format-data

I have been trying to use panelr and then other packages to reshape from wide to long. Here are my variables:

[image]

I tried using panelr's long_panel ('merg_Liz_OSARI_MCST' is the name of the dataframe I am using):

```
panel_long <- merg_Liz_OSARI_MCST %>%
    panelr::long_panel(
    id = "id_number", # existing variable that indexes unique cases
    `wave = "time", # name of the NEW time variable you want
    begin = 1, # first time-related variable suffix in wide data
    end = 3
)
```

I also tried using older packages:

```
merge_long <- merg_Liz_OSARI_MCST |>
    pivot_longer(cols = N_negRT_1:num_go_trials_block_2_3,
    names_to = "Variable",
    values_to = "Value")
```

I also tried:

```
start_pos <- which(names(merg_Liz_OSARI_MCST) == "N_negRT_1")
end_pos <- which(names(merg_Liz_OSARI_MCST) == "num_go_trials_block_2_3")

# Select the variables to reshape

measure_vars <- names(merg_Liz_OSARI_MCST)[start_pos:end_pos]

# Reshape the data

merge_long <- melt(merg_Liz_OSARI_MCST, na.rm = FALSE, value.name = "time", measure.vars = measure_vars, id.vars = "id_number")
```

I can't get anything to work. What can I try next?

I have removed all variables that appeared only in wave 1 and 2 but not 3. I also tried ensuring all variables are in the same order for each wave, but this didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Comment: hi belinda! can you share your data with us? Thanks!